# Why is my C# DLL registered in Excel 2007 but not in Excel 2021?

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I have dll wrote in c##

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Hello
{
  public class HelloWorld
  {
    public String HelloUser(string name)
    {
       return "Hello " + name;
    }
  }
}
```

It's registered - OK

It's added in Tool\References -OK

It's working in Excel2007

[image]

But in Excel2021 tells me NOT registered

[image]

Anyone have any propose of solusion?

Comment: Your Excel 2021 is 64-bit?

Comment: Yes. 
Excel 2007 was x86
Excel 2021 is 64 bit
i rebuilt the dll to 64 bit but i can't register it, do tlb

Comment: I changed cd Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
RegAsm.exe /tlb /codebase c:\ARKUSZDLL\DoBazy.dll

to 

cd Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
RegAsm.exe /tlb /codebase c:\ARKUSZDLL\DoBazy.dll

Generated tlb for excel 64bit 

Thanks :)
PROBLEM SOLVED